# Complex generic java interfaces and classes

Tags: java, generics, libgdx

I have the following classes and interfaces:

```
public interface Curve<T extends Path<Vector2>> {
    List<T> splines();
}
```

---

```
public final class CachedCurve implements Curve<Path<Vector2>> {
    public CachedCurve(final Curve<Path<Vector2>> source) {
        // ...
    }    
    @Override
    public List<Path<Vector2>> splines() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

---

```
public class BezierCurve implements Curve<Bezier<Vector2>> {
    public BezierCurve(List<Vector2> sample, float tresholdPerpDistance) {
        // ...
    }
    @Override
    public List<Bezier<Vector2>> splines() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I use the above like so:

```
Curve<Path<Vector2>> curve = null;
curve = new BezierCurve(new LinkedList<Vector2>(), 10f);  // Compilation error
curve = new CachedCurve(curve);
```

I can't seem to fix this compilation error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from BezierCurve to Curve<Path<Vector2>>
```

---

Maybe it's unclear what I'm trying to do from the (apparently incorrect) code.
I would like to have one generic interface `Curve`. Then I want to have one class that can cache any `Curve` and one that is a special implementation of the `Curve` with Bezier splines. I wish to code this generically so that I can write:

```
Curve<Path<Vector2>> curve = null;
curve = new BezierCurve(/* */);
curve = new CachedCurve(curve);
```

---

Relevant classes from `libGDX`:

- [Path](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Path.html)
- [Bezier](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Bezier.html)
- [Vector2](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2.html)

Comment: Change your class to `class BezierCurve implements Curve<Path<Vector2>>` along with the method signature.

Comment: Look at this ->  

public final class CachedCurve implements Curve<Path<Vector2>> {  
public class BezierCurve implements Curve<Bezier<Vector2>> {  
  
Those classes implements same interface with different generic types, so its not possible to assign BezierCurve to Curve<Path<Vector2>> variable type. You can change generic type of implemented interface in BezierCurve.

Comment: @Tom But I thought it should work somehow because `Bezier<Vector2>` *extends* `Path<Vector2>`.

Comment: Like the duplicate shows/explain: That "extends" logic (polymorphism) doesn't work for generics.